# Can the Pro version of Windows 10 be installed by the Media Creation Tool?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I ran the Media Creation Tool, selected `Create installation media for another PC` and planned to select `Windows 10 Pro` from the `Edition` drop down menu. But all it has is `Windows 10` and `Windows 10 N`.

So - Can the Pro version of Windows 10 be installed by the Media Creation Tool?

(I have an activation key for the pro version.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will install both the Home and Pro edition.

The existing digital entitlement, or product key entered during Setup, will determine which one gets installed.

So unless you want the "N" version, pick "Windows 10". :)

Comment: Not that I can find (I looked ;) ). I believe it's a recent change, so it's probably just not documented yet.