# How to install Win10 on a new SSD if I have upgraded from Windows 8?

Tags: windows-10, reinstall, license-key

I have an oldish laptop HP ProBook 4545s.

I have a license label for Windows 8 on it.

Since a long time ago, I have used free upgrade option to Windows 10.

I intend to replace the HDD with an SSD now and reinstall the OS.

But I have no idea if I can just extract the product key from the current system and use it while reinstalling the system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 - Digital license after PC format](https://superuser.com/questions/1241948/windows-10-digital-license-after-pc-format)

Comment: Another duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/947232/how-to-reinstall-windows-10-on-new-hard-disk/947250#947250

Comment: Worth pointing out Windows 8+ COAs do not have the license printed on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no product key for Windows 10, it now uses
[Digital entitlement](https://www.onmsft.com/news/digital-entitlement-a-new-method-of-activation-in-windows-10)
based on your actual hardware.

Reinstalling Windows 10 should in theory activate itself with no product key.
For more information see
[Activation in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12440/windows-10-activation).

You may also avoid this problem entirely by cloning your system disk to the
new SSD.
See the article
[Best Free Drive Cloning Software](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-drive-cloning-software.htm).